How do I use an existing contact for My Card?
In the Contacts app on iOS 18, there is a My Card section where you can add information about yourself. However, I already have my personal information saved as a different contact.
How can I link the existing contact to My Card?



scroll down to your contact entry
long-press the entry til the menu is shown
select "Make This my Card"


This worked. Worth noting it doesn’t work if you search for your name, you have to scroll down the full unfiltered list.
